# Passing by parameters by value in lisp

Tags: parameters, lisp, common-lisp, pass-by-value

The problem I am having is that I can't get around the fact that lisp passes arrays by value not by reference.

When I researched this problem, the solutions to other people's questions fall into four categories.

1. use a closure
2. think functionally
3. use a macro
4. use a global variable i.e., defparameter

1 & 2) I don't see how the first two solutions are of use. Maybe I don't understand how closures work or how to think functionally.

3) I have made macros instead of functions, but they don't work when the function recurses on itself (unless they do work and I just don't write them correctly).

4) I don't like the idea of globals.

I had this problem in a number of functions I wrote. The most success I had was to return the array when the function returns. But when the function recurses on a subseq of the array then I am stuck.

**I want a general solution, how do I think about these problems differently,** not a solution to the code submitted here.

If you want to refer to a particular piece of code I tried to write, here it is.

I am trying to write some code in Lisp for HackerRank.

I need a sieve of eratosthenes (to get prime numbers).

I wrote the following, which does not work for the above reason. (My logic is probably wrong too.)

```
;sieve-numbers is an array with :initial-element nil
;sieve-numbers represents only the odd numbers starting at 3
;i.e., (aref sieve-numbers n) represents the value 3+n+n
;when the sieve is done (aref sieve-numbers n) is nil if (+ 3 n n) is prime
;removed is the number of values in the sieve-numbers array that have been chopped off the front

(defun sieve-knock (sieve-numbers n)
    "knock out the n'th value, then recurse with a sieve-numbers array that is missing the first n elements until (length sieve-numbers) < n"
    (format t "sieve-knock  (length sieve-numbers) ~a, n ~a~%" (length sieve-numbers) n)
    (cond ((> n (length sieve-numbers)) 'done)
        (t (setf (aref sieve-numbers (1- n)) t)
           (format t "sieve-knock  sieve-numbers ~a~%" sieve-numbers)
           (sieve-knock (subseq sieve-numbers n) n))))

(defun sieve (sieve-numbers removed)
    "the sieve"
    (format t "sieve sieve-numbers ~a, removed ~a~%" sieve-numbers removed)
    (cond 
        ((= 0 (length sieve-numbers)) 'done)
        ((aref sieve-numbers 0) (sieve (subseq sieve-numbers 1) (1+ removed)))
        (t ;found a prime!
           (sieve-knock (subseq sieve-numbers 1) (+ 3 removed removed))
           (sieve (subseq sieve-numbers 1) (1+ removed)))))
```

Comment: Common Lisp passes arrays by reference. The problem is that `SUBSEQ` creates a new array. If you need to be able to pass only a slice of an array, you could use a displaced array, or just pass the start/end indexes as well.

Answer (score 6):

Lisp uses references for arrays. When passing an array to a function, the function has a new reference via a parameter. The array is not copied or changed in any way when the argument is passed.

You can use recursion:

- pass the array, don't copy a new array all the time
- pass the index
- return the array

Example:

```
(defun rknock (sieve-vector pos step)
  (if (>= pos (length sieve-vector))
      sieve-vector
    (progn
      (setf (aref sieve-vector pos) t)
      (rknock sieve-vector (+ pos step) step))))
```

But simple LOOP-based iteration seems to be easier:

```
(defun knock (sieve-vector start step)
  (loop for pos from start below (length sieve-vector) by step 
        do (setf (aref sieve-vector pos) t))
  sieve-vector)
```